# ' Exception in Application start method, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ' while reading and displaying from database

Tags: database, exception, javafx, javafx-2

I am  attempting to read values from MySQL database and display it in a table in JavaFX. I use netbeans IDE. When I run my code I got the exception mentioned in the title. I will post code below:

```
public class ViewSubject extends Application {

private final TableView<Subject> table = new TableView<>();
private final ObservableList<Subject> data
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
final HBox hb = new HBox();

private Connection connect = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
private ResultSet resultSet = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Add Subject");
    stage.setWidth(650);
    stage.setHeight(550);
    stage.setResizable(false);

    final Label label = new Label("Subject Details");
    label.setFont(new Font("Calibri", 20));

    TableColumn sub = new TableColumn("Subject Name");
    sub.setMinWidth(350);
    sub.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Subject, String>("subName"));
    sub.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    sub.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String> t) {
                    ((Subject) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setSubName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn code = new TableColumn("Subject Code");
    code.setMinWidth(130);
    code.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Subject, String>("subCode"));
    code.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    code.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    code.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String> t) {
                    ((Subject) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setSubCode(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn rev = new TableColumn("Revision");
    rev.setMinWidth(130);
    rev.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Subject, String>("subRev"));
    rev.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    rev.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    rev.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Subject, String> t) {
                    ((Subject) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setSubCode(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
    );

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(sub, code, rev);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(10);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("select * from subject");
        writeResultSet(resultSet);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close();
    }

}

private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        String subname = resultSet.getString("subname");
        String code = resultSet.getString("subcode");
        String rev = resultSet.getString("subrev");

        data.add(new Subject(subname, code, rev));
    }
}

private void close() {
    try {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
}
}
```

There is one more class in the package -

```
public class Subject {

    private final SimpleStringProperty sub;
    private final SimpleStringProperty code;
    private final SimpleStringProperty rev;

    Subject(String subName, String subCode, String subRev) {
        this.sub = new SimpleStringProperty(subName);
        this.code = new SimpleStringProperty(subCode);
        this.rev = new SimpleStringProperty(subRev);
    }

    public String getSubName() {
        return sub.get();
    }

    public void setSubName(String subName) {
        sub.set(subName);
    }

    public String getSubCode() {
        return code.get();
    }

    public void setSubCode(String subCode) {
        code.set(subCode);
    }

    public String getSubRev() {
        return rev.get();
    }

    public void setSubRev(String subRev) {
        rev.set(subRev);
    }
}
```

This is the exception details:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at viewsubject.ViewSubject.read(ViewSubject.java:119)
at viewsubject.ViewSubject.start(ViewSubject.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:216)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
... 1 more
```

When the code is ran, a window appears for a fraction of a second and then suddenly closes due to the occurrence of this exception.  Why this exception occurs ? How can remove this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the [MySQL JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) on your classpath.

Perform the Vogella tutorial on [Java and JDBC with MySQL](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html).  Do the whole tutorial step by step, running code each step of the way.  As part of the Vogella tutorial, it tells you how to [setup 3rd party libraries](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#classpath) (like the MySQL JDBC library) in Eclipse.

When posting code, try to post code which matches the stack trace.  The StackTrace reports an error at viewsubject.ViewSubject.read(ViewSubject.java:119) but there is no such read function in your ViewSubject class.

Comment: How did you understood the problem, means how did you found that I don't have the MySQL JDBC driver in my classpath ?